# typecasting syntax not clear

Tags: c, casting, printf

I was reading a book and came across a program to read entries from a `/proc` file.
The program which they mentioned has following line

```
printf("%.*s", (int) n, line);
```

I am not clear with meaning of above line

1. what type of print if above `"%.*s` used instead of `%s`

The code can be read [here](http://www.man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sysinfo/procfs_pidmax.c.html)

Comment: Did you look up the manual page for `printf` ?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt yes  I did read that can you post the excerpts from man page that which section you want to draw my attention.

Comment: **The field width:**
       An  optional decimal digit ... Instead of a decimal digit string one
       may write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to specify that the field width is given in the
       next  argument, ..

Comment: @Jens Gustedt thanks for the information I just checked Ubuntu website http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man3/printf.3.html what I find is the definition you told is only in the online versions of man pages and not in the ones on my laptop.

Comment: ah, that is bizarre. I have that on my computer and I have an unbuntu 10.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Abstract from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/):

> .*    - The precision is not specified in
>   the format string, but as an
>   additional integer value argument
>   preceding the argument that has to be
>   formatted.

So this prints up to n characters from line string.

Answer (score 0):

The cast expression (int) n converts the value of `n` to type `int`. This is because the formatting specifier requires a plain `int`, and I assume (since you didn't include it) the variable `n` has a different type.

Since a different type, like `size_t` might have another size, it would create problems with the argument passing to `printf()` if it wasn't explicitly converted to `int`.